# How do I get flash[:notice] to display in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, view, ruby-on-rails-5, notice

I'm having difficulty getting my notices to display in my Rails 5 view.  I have this `before_filter` method set up in a controller:

```
def check_email_confirmed!
  redirect_to controller: "users", action: "edit", notice: 'Please confirm your email.' unless current_user.email_confirmed
end
```

and in my view I have this

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p class="flash-notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

but despite the fact that I know the notice is getting set (I see it in my URL) the above is not getting invoked in my view (I see no HTML with the `class="flash-notice"`).

Is there some other way I should be setting flash notices in a redirect?  Or should I be using a redirect at all (someone told me there might be some security risks in embedding messages in the URL query string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently setting a parameter with the key `notice`, not setting the flash in your session.

To accomplish this the way you're doing it you would have to do:

```
<p class="flash-notice"><%= params[:notice] %></p>
```

Most Rails apps that I've worked on set the `session[:flash]` in the controller method, in which case you would do:

```
unless current_user.email_confirmed
  redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
  flash[:notice] = 'Please confirm your email.'
end
```

Unless you have a good reason to pass the notice text as a URL param, I'd recommend doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
flash[:notice] = 'bla'
redirect_to controller: "users", action: "edit"
```

I'm pretty sure that

```
redirect_to edit_user_path(user), notice: 'bla'
```

Will also work. For some reason your syntax apparently doesn't pick up the notice modifier. But you'll have to assign user to your current user for that to work obviously.